# Python regular expression to capture last word with missing line feed

Tags: python, regex

I need to capture words separated by tabs as illustrated in the image below.

[image]

The expression `(.*?)[\t|\n]` works well, except for the last line where a line feed is missing. Can anyone suggest a modification of the regular expression to also match the last word, i.e. Cheyenne? [Link to code example](https://regex101.com/r/Z6KmDo/1)

Comment: Can't use the CSV module, The data that I show in the question is constructed just to illustrate the problem. The real data set I'm working with is very different and needs a lot of cleaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `[\t|\n]` with `(\t|$)`.

BTW, `[\t|\n]` is a character class, so the pipe `|` is literal here. You probably meant `[\t\n]`.

Comment: OP does not want `[\t\n]`, but `[^\n\t]+`

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/K8L9rw/1

Comment: @Wiktor Yeah, that's a better solution. Though just to be clear, I'm not saying to use `[\t\n]`, just mentioning the common mistake of putting a pipe in a character class. I'm actually recommending `(\t|$)`.

Comment: Changing to `(\t|$)` solves the problem as outlined in the question. But let's say I want to match a repeating pattern of cities, as shown here (https://regex101.com/r/D8DIkB/3). Is that possible?

Comment: @John That's a different question, so you could [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for that.